# Class no funciona con clone jquery

Tags: jquery, clone

tengo un problema al crear input dinamicos con clone, necesito que el input clonado me acepte una clase como por ejemplo tengo una clase que valida que el input solo acepte valores numericos, el problema es que al clonar el input la clase no funciona, osea que me acepta letras, puntos, etc.

Quisiera saber si hay una forma para que al clonar el input tambien me acepte la clase que yo necesito.

Ahorita lo tengo asi, no es con clone, pero igual la class no funciona. La clase que necesito que funcione es la input-number

```
var newinput = '<div class="field">';
                newinput = newinput + '<label class="nsubsidio">Subsidio:</label>';
                newinput = newinput + '<input type="text" name="sub[]" maxlength=9 class="input-number" onkeyup="verSubsidio(this);" />';  
                newinput = newinput + '<input type="button" class="removerbtn" value="X">';          
                newinput = newinput + '</div>';
              $(".div_subsidio").append(newinput);
```

class input-number

```
$('.input-number').on('input', function () { 
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        });
```

Comment: Necesitas agregar tu codigo, de otra forma es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Podrías subir que hace la clase input-number? solo la tienes para uso de css o también le agregas alguna funcionalidad (Por ejemplo, inicializas que cuando cargue la pagina todos los elementos que tengan esta clase se valide lo de los numeros)?

Comment: la clase la utilizo para validar que en el input solo se pueda ingresar numeros$('.input-number').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
  });

Comment: Entonces si la utilizas desde JS, cuando agregues elementos dinámicos aunque tengan la clase no se validaran ya que no existian cuando el DOM fue creado, por lo que debes hacer es volver a inicializar la funcionalidad de la clase una vez agregado el elemento dinámico al DOM (HTML)

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo, te lo agradeceria mucho, no comprendo a que te refieres con inicializar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza que busque en el documento, en lugar de los que contengan esa clase, ya que los elementos creados dinamicamente no existen aun cuando se carga ese código, mejor busca en todo el documento

```
    $(document).on('input','.input-number', function () { 
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    });
```

Con este codigo la logica del codigo busca en todo el documento (DOM) los elementos que tengan input-number sean dinamicos o sean creados desde HTML y ejecuta la validación

Comment: de esta forma me ha funcionado, te lo agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los elementos dinamicos no existen cuando el handler se inicializa.  Para que funcione, necesitas anclar el handler a un elemento que exista cuando la inicializacion se ejecuta.  Intentalo asi:

```
$('.div_subsidio').on('input', '.input-number' function () { 
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    });
```

Comment: gracias, por la ayuda lo comprobe de esta forma pero no funcionaba, lo unico que habia que cambiar era "div_subsidio" por document